# css for required character * to red color in all pages

Tags: css, validation, required

I have * in all pages with forms. Can I change * to red color for all required fields through out my site with out wrapping it in div or some other wrapper?

Comment: Need some more context here. An example maybe?

Comment: Where are the asterisks located at? You can use a simple regex to match the asterisk character in, say, `<label>` elements, and wrap them with a simple `<span>` element, then use CSS to style accordingly.

Comment: They are next to labels in all screens. All my controls are auto generated and adding span is complex part. So I am trying to figure out if I can change content in pages rather than wrapping span or div around *.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope it will help you, try with jquery, it will all **" * "** and chages the color to red

```
   $("body").html($("body").html().replace(/[*]/g,'<span style="color:red">*</span>'));
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RRfFr/74/)

Answer (score 1):

Assume your HTML looks like this:

```
 <input type="text" name="myName" /><span>*</span>
```

Then your CSS might look like this

```
 input + span{
     color: #ff0000;
 }
```

That might get you close to what you want . . .

Comment: * Other reds are available . . .

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `::after` psuedo element to add a red asterisk to any required input field, that way you don't even need to manually add the asterisk yourself. Assuming the HTML structure is similar to this:

```
<div>
  <label for="input-field">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="input-field" id="input-field" required />
</div>
```

Then the following CSS will add a red asterisk to the end of any label in the same div as a required input or textarea field.

```
div:has(*:is(input, textarea):required) > label::after {
    content: " *";
    color: red;
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want a separate div for each input, you might be able to use the `aria-labelledby` attribute of an input to reference it's label. This might be a better solution even, but I haven't done it this way.